# データフレームである列の値に特定の文字列を含む場合、追加した列に指定した文字列を表示したい

Tags: python, pandas

どのようにコードを書き換えれば「期待する結果」のような出力がだせるのかわかりません。
お知恵をいただければ幸いです。

#### データセット

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([["tanaka", 81], ["naka", 63], ["ka", 89], ["saitou", 93], ["ito", 56], ["suzuki", 76]], columns=['name', 'score'])
df
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 【試したこと】条件列追加コード

```
conditions = [
'ta' in df['name'],
'su' in df['name']
]
 
choices = ['ta','su']
 
df['test1'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0) #defaultを入れることでelseの代わりになる！
df
```

##### その結果（すべてデフォルト値のゼロになってしまう）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

##### 期待する結果

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
conditions = ['ta' in df['name'], 'su' in df['name']]
```

ですと、`[False, False]`となってしまいますので、

```
conditions = [df['name'].str.contains('ta'), df['name'].str.contains('su')]
```

とします。

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([["tanaka", 81], ["naka", 63], ["ka", 89],
                   ["saitou", 93], ["ito", 56], ["suzuki", 76]],
                  columns=['name', 'score'])

choices = ['ta', 'su']
conditions = [df['name'].str.contains(c) for c in choices]
df['test1'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=0)
print(df)
```

| name | score | test1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tanaka | 81 | ta |
| naka | 63 | 0 |
| ka | 89 | 0 |
| saitou | 93 | 0 |
| ito | 56 | 0 |
| suzuki | 76 | su |